# Find out row index by searching in column in ag grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I need to find the newly submitted student record by name in ag grid  in specific column and pass the row id in flashCell method to highlight the new entry

```
  flashNewStudentRecord(rowIndex: number) {
    var rowNode1 = this.gridApi.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(rowIndex);
    this.gridApi.flashCells({
      rowNodes: [rowNode1],
    });
  }
```

now I have to search the student name in the client side data in column 'Student Name ' and get the row Index to pass it in above method , any suggestion how to achieve that

Cant search through my data source for the grid as its async , and its behaving weird

Comment: please post a more complete example of your code in order to reproduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this one way from the `cellRenderFramework`. there you can get the `rowIndex` from the params.

here is an example :

```
 cellRendererFramework: (params) => {
     if(params.column?.columnId === "yourExactcolumnYouWantToTestOn"){
        if(prams.value ==="yourValueToTestOn"){
          //call your flash function, or the best would be to delay it, using setTimeOut
          flashNewStudentRecord(params.rowIndex)
        }
     }
     return <AgGridCellRenderer>         
            </AgGridCellRenderer>
 },
```